# SASS function that generates css

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I have a sass function that generates CSS codes which is mainly CSS variables like the following examples:

```
--my-primary-color: red;
--object-1-left: 12px;
--object-2-left: 8px;
--object-3-left: calc(var(--object-1-left) + var(--object-2-left));
...
//and so on
```

The function generates the above result except for it is all in one line.
The problem is how to add the function's result to the main scss of css file :

```
:root{
   my-function(param1, param2 ,...);  //not working : error: expected {
}

// using without :root :

    my-function(param1, param2 ,...);  //not working : error: expected {
```

but if add a css code to it which has an invalid final result, the sass file will be compiled:

```
p{
   font-size : my-function(param1, param2 ,...);
}

// the reuslt: ====>

p{
   font-size : --my-primary-color: red;--object-1-left: 12px; --object-2-left: 8px;--object-3-left: calc(var(--object-1-left) + var(--object-2-left)); ...
}
```

Comment: make a function that generate the code *with* :root

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have tested that and does not work. The sass compiler faces error independent to any fucntion result.